# Generate SQL From Table names from List

Tags: mysql, excel, database, navicat

In my job we have a number of tables that store client information. Each client has an individual ID number. The convention we use for naming the tables is a letter prefix and then the ID. In order to do my job and work on issues that come up, we currently have to write a single SQL statement in excel with the ID as a cell reference wherever we need to use the ID (for example to construct the FROM clause). Is there any way I can write the query a single time and have it swap out the ID suffix into a single query? The current method is to use a series of unions. The where clauses and selects are all identical on the queries (generally), the only difference is the ID on the FROM and any subsequent joins, as well as possibly a static field to track which table/account individual rows of data come from.

The tables take a form like the following:

```
Select * from "some letter"101 Limit 1
Select * from "some other letter"101 limit 1
Select * from "some other letter"101 limit 1
Select * from "some other letter"101 limit 1
etc...
```

So a query may look like:

```
SELECT '100' as id, field, field, field, field 
FROM D100 where field between 'xxxxx' AND 'xxxx' AND field = 'xxxx' AND field= 'xxxx'  union
SELECT '102' as id, field, field, field, field 
FROM D102 where field between 'xxxx' AND 'xxxx' AND field = 'xxxxx' AND field = 'xxxxx'  union
SELECT '103' as id, field, field, field, field 
FROM D103 where field between 'xxxxx' AND 'xxxxxx' AND field = 'XXXX' AND field = 'XXXXX'  union ....
```

I almost never need to query every table, and generally I have a list of IDs I need to check, so ideally I would just supply a list to a single query that will automatically swap the IDs where needed.

Is there a better way to do this? The lack of data is a security precaution

Also, I do not have write access to this database, only read.

To elaborate, each client has a number of tables, and there are a large number of clients, the tables are identified by a prefix letter designating the data it contains followed by the client ID. Typically a work request will come in and all I have is a list of IDs. The current way everyone in my office approaches it is to build the query in excel with concatenation, I am looking for a way to only have a single query but not repeat the whole query for each table with the IDs I am interested in and get a single result. The union technique we are using works, but I wonder if there is a way to do this faster.

EDIT - Parameters may be the answer, but these are not stored procedures

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic SQL?  That way your stored procedure/view can take in suffix param and use it in your query.  If you haven't and need an example, I'll provide one and you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: why did you not include the other databases?

Comment: You have both MySQL and SQLServer tagged, which is it?

Comment: Why do you have tables for each client? It would be much easier to query an `A` (or `D` or `C` or `I`) table with a `client_id` column. Is re-architecting the database structure out of the question?

Comment: Nick, I'm really low on the totem pole and this structure existed long before I started working here (and probably before I even graduated school), so, yeah, it is out of the question

Comment: Bad database design use customer id as a foreign key and solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit of information missing from your question, but this query will generate SQL for you:

```
select 'select * from ' + table_name + ' where field between ''xx'' and ''xx'''
from information_schema.tables
where table_name like '[a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: This appears to be in the direction I want to go, but when I replace the dummy data with my own the query returns a single column with the literal text after the first select as the header and every row displays 0.
Does it matter that I am running the queries as I write them in the editor and they are not stored procedures?

Comment: This code is meant to be run from SSMS, not from within a stored procedure.  It sounds like you have made a mistake in the SELECT line.

Comment: Would running it in Navicat against mysql also cause that issue?